# Not able to move image in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am a beginner in Python. I am trying to shift image using pygame module. But I am not able to shift position of the image in python. Can you help me understand what I am doing wrong?

```
import pygame, sys                             
from pygame.locals import *                    
pygame.init()                                  

image = pygame.image.load("ball.jpg")
image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (100, 100))

imgrect = image.get_rect()

Canvas = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption('Text Input')

imgrect.left = 200
imgrect.top = 200

Canvas.blit(image, imgrect)
pygame.display.update()

while True:                                    
    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == KEYDOWN :              
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:          
                pygame.quit()                  
                sys.exit()     
            if event.key == K_UP:
                imgrect.top += 1
            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                imgrect.top -= 1
```

Comment: Use lowercase names (like `canvas`) for variables instead of `Canvas`. The second one is used for classes and it might confuse other programmers if you mix the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic game loop should do three things: handle events, update and draw. I see the logic where you update the position of the rectangle, but you don't redraw the image at the new position.

I've added lines at the bottom of the game loop to draw the scene.

```
while True: 
    # handle events
    # update logic

    # draw
    Canvas.fill((0, 0, 0))  # Clears the previous image.
    Canvas.blit(image, imgrect)  # Draws the image at the new position.
    pygame.display.update()  # Updates the screen.
```

Comment: Also, if the background is another color than black, just change R, G, B values in `Canvas.fill((R, G, B))` to match the current background color. Or if there's an background image, replace `Canvas.fill((0, 0, 0))` with `Canvas.blit(bg_image, (0, 0))`.